# Parsing JSON and looping through replies

Tags: c#, json

I'm trying to parse the following json code: http://www.soyoustart.com/fr/js/dedicatedAvailability/availability-data.json

However i'm getting a bit confused with the looping through data, I can't work out how to get the loop in to go through the different classes and let me reach the list of availability.

I thought it'd be in mydata, but that seems to just be one big clump. How do I filter it out so I can loop through all the different availabilities?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    DB db = new DB();
    DataTable dtServers = db.GetDataTable("select * from SYS_Servers");
    string htmlCode;
    var json = "";
    using (var webClient = new System.Net.WebClient())
    {
        json = webClient.DownloadString("http://www.soyoustart.com/fr/js/dedicatedAvailability/availability-data.json");
    }

    dynamic myData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, typeof(object));
    String x = "moo";
}

public class Zone
{
    public string availability { get; set; }
    public string zone { get; set; }
}

public class Availability
{
    public string reference { get; set; }
    public List<Zone> zones { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Availability> availability { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        DB db = new DB();
        DataTable dtServers = db.GetDataTable("select * from SYS_Servers");
        string htmlCode;
        var json = "";
        using (var webClient = new System.Net.WebClient())
        {
            json = webClient.DownloadString("http://www.soyoustart.com/fr/js/dedicatedAvailability/availability-data.json");
        }

        RootObject myData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, typeof(RootObject)) as RootObject;
        foreach (var availability in myData.availability)
        {
            //do something with availability
        }
        String x = "moo";
    }
    public class Zone
    {
        public string availability { get; set; }
        public string zone { get; set; }
    }

    public class Availability
    {
        public string reference { get; set; }
        public Zone[] zones { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public Availability[] availability { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Ah really helpful. How do I loop through the RootObject?

Comment: Just use `for` or `foreach`?

Comment: Sorry i get that, but what am i looping over? A rootobject?

Comment: Its availability property: `foreach (var availability in myData.availability){...}`